# How to retrieve several elements following each other with the same class name in a web page with selenium python using x path or findclass?

Tags: python, selenium

[web page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XL7i.png)

`e=driver.find_element_by_class_name("place_box")`

> Its return only the first (place_box) infos but i would like to get the infos from all (places boxs), i've already try with the xpath but i can't get it to work properly.....

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_class_name()` would return the first matched element i.e. first (place_box), where as you need all (places boxs) i.e. you expect a *list*. So you have to use `find_elements_by_class_name("place_box")`.

---

### Solution

Your effective code block will be:

```
 e = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("place_box")
```